# Change required element style if empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple forms, where I want to change the background-color + border-color of the input field whenever a required field is not filled it. My problem is, I know how to do this manually for each element with it's ID.

What I need is to automatically select all elements that have html `required` and if they are empty, change their styling.

This is my code now:

```js
function showHideUserpanel() {
    var nbform = document.getElementById("userpanel");
    var emailcheckvar = document.getElementById("emailcheck");
    var voornaamcheckvar = document.getElementById("voornaamcheck");
    var voorwaardencheckvar = document.getElementById("voorwaardencheck");
    var aanmelding_succesvol = document.getElementById("bedankt-melding");

    if (emailcheckvar.value !== '' && voornaamcheckvar.value !== '' && voorwaardencheckvar.checked == true) {
        nbform.style.display = 'none';
        aanmelding_succesvol.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        nbform.style.display = 'block';

        if (emailcheckvar.value == '') {
            emailcheckvar.style.backgroundColor = '#FF555526';
            emailcheckvar.style.borderColor = '#FF5555';
        }

        if (voornaamcheckvar.value == '') {
            vaarnaamcheckvar.style.backgroundColor = '#FF555526';
            voornaamcheckvar.style.borderColor = '#FF5555';
        }
    }
}
```

Where variable nbform is my form and aanmelding_succesvol is my succes message. My form has ID `userpanel`. As you see I can change the styling per element. However I have multiple pages, with multiple forms, all with different ID's. So I'd not prefer making a rule for 50 different elements.

Does anyone know how to do this? (jquery if easier to implement also possible)

EDIT: I only want it to happen on click of the form submit button, so my button looks like:

```
<input type="submit" value="inschrijven" onclick="showHideUserpanel()"/>
```

Then if the field is empty, the styling should be changed.

Comment: You might like to consider using a validation plugin eg [jquery validate](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

querySelectorAll will iterate select ALL the elements that have the required class. then you can loop through all of them and apply your changes.

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.required');
elements.forEach(element => {
   if (element.value === "") {
     element.style.display = '#FF555526';
     element.style.borderColor = '#FF5555';
   } else {
     ...
   }
});
```

Comment: Using this with [required] instead of .required works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS like this:

```
input[value='']:required{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

It should match required inputs with value attribute being an empty string.

You should probably make the selector a bit more specific though if you don't want this to take effect on every input.

Edit:
Actually, the above method seems to keep the red border after you type the value in.

A different approach then would be by using ":placeholder-shown" selector.

```
input:placeholder-shown:required{
     border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Note: this only works if you actually have placeholders set on your inputs.

Also if you only want this to happen after the form was submitted, you can add a class to the form (or some wrapper around all the fields) like "submitted-form" and then specify the selector a bit further:

```
.submitted-form input:placeholder-shown:required{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Possibly: `input[required][value='']`

Comment: Just thought of that as well. Edited :)

Comment: Hi, I just edited my post. It should only happen after clicking on the button (form submit). Not initially.

Comment: I've actually noticed that this doesn't change properly when you type something in..

Comment: Updated the answer with something that actually works and addressed the updated question

Comment: I think this is by far the method that requires the least JS. It works perfectly, cool! Thanks! One more question: do you know if you can use this with checkbox label :before? So something like label:before:required {} ?

Comment: if your label comes after the checkbox you can do something like:
    input[type=checkbox]:required:not(:checked) + label{ color: red; }

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work (I assume jQuery is there because of the tag).

```js
$('[required]').on('change', function(){
    if(typeof this.checked !== 'undefined' && !this.checked) {
        // required checkbox is not checked, set the style here
    }
    else if(!this.value) {
        // required text field is not filled, set the style here
    }
})
```

If you don't use jQuery here, `[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[required]'))` gives you an array of HTML elements to use `addEventListener` on.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myForm [required]").each(function() {
    $(this).on("input change blur", function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("invalid", this.value === "")
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.invalid {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  Voornaam: <input type="text" name="naam" value="" required /> Email: <input type="email" name="email" value="" required />
</form>
```

Vanilla

```js
const check = e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  tgt.classList.toggle("invalid", tgt.value === "")
};
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("#myForm [required]")].forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener("input", check);
    elem.addEventListener("change", check);
    elem.addEventListener("blur", check);
  })
})
```

```css
.invalid {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  Voornaam: <input type="text" name="naam" value="" required /> Email: <input type="email" name="email" value="" required />
</form>
```